# Making invoice and trying to add a new row using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm making an invoice page with `HTML` ,`PHP` and `jQuery`. I am trying to have a button to add a new item to the invoice. When the button is pushed to add a new item it should insert a new `.row` below the existing ones. following is the `html` snippet that needs to be added

```
<div class="row" id="div4">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" id="inputItem" placeholder="Item #4" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" id="inputItem" placeholder="Description" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="text" id="inputItem" placeholder="Qty." class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="text" id="inputItem" placeholder="Tax" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" id="inputItem" placeholder="Item Total" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

`#div4` is the `id` of the last row.

I've tried the jQuery code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add").click(function() {
            $("#div4").append("cant get html below to replicate");
        });
    });
</script>
```

any help would be awesome thanks in advance.

Comment: *id="inputItem"* must be unique

Comment: so would each div and input need unique id's? if so how would those be added to the jquery code? thanks for your help

Comment: @jeffPo you can use a class name instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you can try something like this
Assuming following is the button for adding new item,

```
<input type='button' id='addrow' value='Add item' />
```

script

```
$('#add').click(function(){
  var n= $('.row').length+1;
  var temp = $('.row:first').clone();
  $('input:first',temp).attr('placeholder','Item #'+n)
  $('.row:last').after(temp);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/57hRd/2/)

*side note: you need to remove the `id`'s from a dynamic template, you could use common `class` instead.*

Comment: try this.


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add").on("click",function() {
            $("#div4").appendTo("cant get
html below to replicate");
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: @JohnKariuki sorry, i didn't get you..?

Comment: Tilwin your script works perfect but when i updated my file the button does nothing. any ideas?

Comment: @jeffPo which button you're referring to, the add button..? is it being added dynamically in your file…?

Comment: sorry about that, the add button appears on the screen but a new row doesnt populate when pressed

Comment: @try adding an `alert` or `console.log` in buttons click handler, let me know if it triggers or not, if it doesn't  check for any errors in console. Make sure you've added `jquery`.